# Ping-Pong Mechanism in WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, ubuntu-18.04

I am developing an application in which whenever the server disconnects due to any external issue, I want that the client gets informed somehow of the recent connection lost. 
I have read that a ping pong mechanism can be used to detect connection lost. I tried doing:

```
function onMessage(event)
{
 if(event.data=="__Pong__")
  {
    //connection still alive
  }
}
```

Is this way correct to determine if the client got a pong message from the server? Or is there another way?

Comment: You can try to use `close` and `error` events of WebSocket

Comment: @yuko Thanks for your reply. I have one question, I don't understand when is close event called? Is it when the server gets disconnected?

Comment: The event is called when connection gets closed in general, by server or client. You can pass `code` param to  the `close` function in order to filter normal closures in your `close` event. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent)

Comment: Thanks it worked! I just restarted the websocket (by creating a new one) whenever close event was called.